# Firebase best data structure practice for large dataset

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have 20K users and each user has ~100 products (that is ~2M products). I have two solutions:

Solution 1

```
{
"products": {
   "product1": {
     "uid": "uid1",
     "cat": "category1",
     "title": "Produc1",
     "url": "url1"
   },
   "product2": {
     "uid": "uid2",
     "cat": "category2",
     "title": "Product2",
     "url": "url2"
   },
   "product3": {
     "uid": "uid2",
     "cat": "category1",
     "title": "Product3",
     "url": "url3"
   },
    ...
}
```

Solution 2:

```
{
"stuff": {
   "uid1": {
        "products": {
           "product1": {
             "cat": "category1",
             "title": "Produc1",
             "url": "url1"
           },
           "product2": {
             "cat": "category2",
             "title": "Product2",
             "url": "url2"
           },
           "product3": {
             "cat": "category1",
             "title": "Product3",
             "url": "url3"
           },
   },
   "uid2": {
    ...
}
```

I want to get all products for a specific user (I already know the uid).

Question 1: In terms of speed, which solution is better?

Question 2: In Solution 2, how can I use child_added, child_changed etc events?

(first thoughts by me: Solution 1 with filter by uid option seems slower to me than Solution 2 by just getting the specific child node (for 2M records), am I right? But, in the case of Solution 2: can I retrieve the list in the 2nd level /stuff/$uid/products and then use push, child_added events etc?)

thanks!

Comment: Since the full scope and range of queries was not specified, it's hard to provide and answer. However, if your sole goal is *get all products for a specific user* then solution 1 is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, my intension is to grab all products for a specific user as fast as it can be, and also to watch for changes in products nodes (for this specific user). You mentioning the Solution 1 as a way to go, but in terms of speed, should I use filter() or something else? My guessing is that filtering among 2M products will be slow..

Comment: Nope. We've tested it. You're not returning 2M nodes - you are returning a subset. Even if it was 50k, it's still very quick. HOWEVER... and this is the real issue; returning that many nodes is going to push the client devices capacity. That size of dataset may not be be the best solution. We don't know the scope of the project but I would recommend a different strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we are talking about speed, the most important rule in Firebase is to have the data as flatten as possible. According to this rule, i suggest you remodel your database like this:

```
firebase-url
    |
    --- users
    |     |
    |     ---- userId_1
    |     |       |
    |     |       ---- userName: "John"
    |     |       |
    |     |       ---- userAge: 30
    |     |       |
    |     |       ---- products
    |     |              |
    |     |              ---- productId_1 : true
    |     |              |
    |     |              ---- productId_2 : true
    |     |
    |     ---- userId_2
    |             |
    |             ---- userName: "Anna"
    |             |
    |             ---- userAge: 25
    |             |
    |             ---- products
    |                    |
    |                    ---- productId_3 : true
    |                    |
    |                    ---- productId_4 : true
    |
    ---- products
       |
       ---- productId_1
           |
           ---- productName: "product_1"
           |
           ---- users
              |
              ---- userId_1: true
              |
              ---- userId_2: true
```

In this way you can query your database very simple to display all the users that have access to a single product: `firebase-url/products/productId/users/` and also all the products of a specifc user: `firebase-url/users/userId/products/`

And this how it can be done in code:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId).child("products");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String productId = (String) ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products").child(productId);
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     String productName = (String) dataSnapshot.child("productName").getValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            productsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

To learn more about structuring your Firebase database correctly please read this [post](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. One question: in your solution how can I retrieve the products (and their details) for a specific user with just one query?

Comment: You're welcome! No, you cannot with a single query but this is the point. What you are saying is in fact your 2'nd solution. Why is bad? Because all product details are nested in each user node and this is not a good practice. If you do so and you put a listener on a specific user to get, let's say the name, you'll download all products data, because are nested inside. This will slow the process and download lost of Mega's. To solve this, you need to put a listener on `firebase-url/users/userId/products/` and based on the `productId` to query again to find all the products necessary details.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty explainable. Something that scares me, though, is that I have to query multiple times to get the details (not just the titles) of all products for a specific user (if I use a filter we fallback in my 1st Solution). Am I understand correctly?

Comment: Becuase Firebase is a NoSQL databate the relationship between nodes is done this way. You don't have to be scared. I have updated my answer. So, please take a look. The `products` and the `users` remain as separated nodes and the relationship is done based on `userId` and `productId`.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: While this is an answer, it could be greatly simplified with a [Deep Path Query](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html). The query would be on the products node, users/userId_1 is true. That would prevent having to iterate over data and also multiple hits to the database, increasing performance.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time and effort. The code provided by @Alex is definitely a way to go, even if the for loop scares me! 
- Alex: I do not understand why we need user references in product nodes - you are not using them in your code and if I download a product node then all user information will be downloaded too
- Jay: please take a look on my comment bellow the initial post

Comment: You're welcome! If you don't need user references in product nodes, than don't use it. The purpose in this example was to show you how things work in Firebase. Understanding this, from now on you can use this whatever you want. If you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: @DimitrisSp You are going to run into issues with this solution based on the size of your data set. As soon as you have to load an iterate over 50k nodes of data it's going to become unresponsive with delays as not only are 50k nodes returned (Ram hog), you need to to iterate over them, so that's 50k additional hits to the database. Getting it all at one time would (mostly) alleviate that issue. But, see my comment to your post as well. It may be time to explore other options.

Comment: He does not need to iterate over 50k nodes, he will iterate only on the specific nodes which are far from 50k. Let take an example, if he needs to put on listener on `firebase-url/users/userId/products/` it will return a few k.

Comment: Let me explain a little bit: I expect 2M nodes from 20K users and that is around 100 products per user (do you have more than 100 products in your Amazon wish list at the same time?200?). So my question about filtering can be refined as follows: is there any performance issue when I'll 'select' (using filter() ) 100 records from 2M total records?

Comment: When you'll have your products separately and not nested under another node, and you will proced as explained above, there will not be any problems. Also i suggest you use some limitations in your query. As you probably know, if do so, in your `dataSnahshot` will be present only filtered data.